# Is it possible to use Firebase Cloud Messaging in iOS app without Apple Developer Program?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wonder if it is possible to use firebase cloud messaging with iOS app without Apple Developer Program?

***For instance, I am asking whether I can set up certificates for Apple Push Notification?***

I haven't found much information on the web.

Comment: Are you asking wether you will be able to use FCM w/O  Apple Developer Program?

Comment: @WhiteRabbit If that is what you are asking then actually put that in your question.

Answer (score 7):

No, It's not possible. We must have to upload .p12 file on FCM for cloud messaging and so generating certificates and .p12 file we must need an account of apple developer.

Comment: If you're hesitating to apply for Apple Dev Program just for your portfolio app because you don't want to pay $100 - don't worry, you'll return these and much more money after your first iOS project would get paid ;)